# How can I remove or edit the per page section in Products list (X-cart)

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

I need to edit some css but I couldn't find the place to change the template for per page dropdownlist

I guess the code is generated by $content variable but how can I modify it ???

If you have a clue, please answer me... thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this template: /skin/common_files/customer/main/per_page.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Change function in {root}/include/search.php file/

For example:

```
    $perPageValues = array();

    for ($i = 50; 460 >= $i; $i = $i + 100) {
        $perPageValues[] = $i;
    }

    $smarty->assign('per_page',         'Y');
    $smarty->assign('per_page_values',  $perPageValues);

}
```